# Camel - RoutePolicy based on query

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a few camel processes that is on a timer and some routes that are polling JMS endpoint.  I would like to implement a `RoutePolicy` to run a DB query to determine if it should continue onto with the route or not. Possibly, in the "`onExchangeBegin`" method, if that is the correct location.

I know I can put a check in the beginning of the route which may be suffice in a timer endpoint, but that approach won't work in JMS polling because it will pull the jms payload.  Additionally, I would like to share this route policy across multiple routes.

If someone can point me to sample code or approach, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Route policy you have to implement the RoutePolicy interface, or use class org.apache.camel.support.RoutePolicySupport that is provided by Camel as a convenience. So your policy class must be like

```
class MyRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport{...}
```

As you said in your description, `onExchangeBegin` will not work in JMS case because it will consume your message, so the message will be lost.

One way I though that may work is to **disable/enable the corresponding route that listens to JMS queue**.

So, you can create a new route starting from timer, let's say every 10s, that will run the DB query you want. In this route you will apply your policy and you will use `onExchangeDone`. Thus, if the result is ok, then enable the JMS route, or else disable it. Something like this:

```
public void onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange) {

    //check the result of the query
    ... exchange.getIn().getBody() ...

    // If result is ok (enable JMS route)
    CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();

    if(ok){
        try {
            context.startRoute("JMSRoute");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getExceptionHandler().handleException("Exception occured during staring route ", e);
        }
    }
    // If result is not ok (disable JMS route)
    else{
        try {
            context.getInflightRepository().remove(exchange, "JMSRoute");
            context.stopRoute("JMSRoute");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getExceptionHandler().handleException("Exception occured during stoping route ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you wan to add the same route policy in many routes you can just add the routePolicyRef(XML DSL) or routePolicy(Java DSL) in your routes. For example

```
<bean id="myRoutePolicy" class="com.xxx.MyRoutePolicy"/>

<route id="route1" routePolicyRef="myRoutePolicy"> ... </route>
<route id="route2" routePolicyRef="myRoutePolicy"> ... </route>
<route id="route3" routePolicyRef="myRoutePolicy"> ... </route>
```

Or use the RoutePolicyFactory, see more at https://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html section *Using RoutePolicyFactory*.